# localhost:8080 всегда перенаправляет на ww.eclipse.org

Tags: сокет, tcp-ip, localhost

Я использовала tcp/ip monitor чтобы мониторить сайт эклипса с localhost:8080 (как пример, чтобы посмотреть как работает tcp/ip). Я удалила этот монитор, но не остановила его. Теперь localhost:8080 всегда перенаправляет меня на сайт эклипса.
Я пробовала открыть идентичный монитор и закрыть его, открыть монитор на тот же сокет 8080 но с другим host name (при вводе  localhost:8080 меня перенаправляет на сайт эклипса, а не на новый host name), отключиться от интернета (адрес всё равно меняется на [www.eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org), но на сайт не доступен, естественно), удалить eclipse - ничего не работает. Я попробовала открыть ещё один монитор на сокет 9000 с host name [www.eclipse.org](http://www.eclipse.org), запустить, остановить и теперь и этот сокет тоже застрял на этом сайте, но этот монитор я не удалила.

Как это исправить?

Comment: Можете уточнить какая у вас OS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы уже пробовали перезагружать компьютер, возможно проблема в файлике hosts.
https://remontka.pro/hosts-file-windows-10/